# django-oscar / django-oscar-api: huge number of queries to render the ProductSerializer

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am using django-oscar with my own Product class, and a serializer for Django REST Framework. I am finding that adding some properties which are stored as attributes results in a huge number of queries.

For example as soon as I add "legacy_title" (which is an attribute I've added) to the serializer's fields, the number of queries made to render this result goes up from 3 to 70. I have 21 products in my databases.

```py
from oscarapi.serializers.product import ProductSerializer as CoreProductSerializer


class ProductSerializer(CoreProductSerializer):
    class Meta(CoreProductSerializer.Meta):
        fields = (
            "url",
            "id",
            "description",
            "slug",
            "upc",
            "title",
            "structure",
            "legacy_title",
        )
```

My Product class:

```py
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct


def attribute_error_as_none(callable_):
    try:
        return callable_()
    except AttributeError:
        return None


class Product(AbstractProduct):
    @property
    def legacy_title(self) -> str:
        return attribute_error_as_none(lambda: self.attr.legacy_title) or self.title
```

I'm using django-oscar-api's built-in `ProductList` view. If I add a few more fields which are backed by attributes, then the query count keeps going up, to 84 queries for these 21 products.

Then add things like `children`, `recommendations`, and `images`, and it takes 240 queries to render this result!

How can I get the query count under control? The endpoint to fetch all products is by far the slowest API endpoint in my entire backend and is becoming a problem. Should I  override the `ProductList` view, with a custom `queryset` with some `select_related` or `prefetch_related` peppered in? I tried `prefetch_related("attributes")` but that only increases the query count by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brought the number of queries back under control by overriding `django-oscar-api`'s `ProductList`.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
from oscarapi.views.product import ProductList as CoreProductList

ProductAttributeValue = get_model("catalogue", "ProductAttributeValue")


class ProductList(CoreProductList):
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get the list of items for this view.
        This can be overridden in subclasses to provide custom behavior.
        """
        queryset = super().get_queryset()

        # Prefetch attributes to reduce number of queries
        queryset = queryset.select_related("parent", "product_class").prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "attribute_values",
                queryset=ProductAttributeValue.objects.select_related("attribute", "value_option"),
                to_attr="prefetched_attr_values",
            ),
            "children",
            "images",
        )

        return queryset
```

To make use of these `prefetched_attr_values`, my `Product` model looks like this:

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct


def attribute_error_as_none(callable_):
    try:
        return callable_()
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def get_prefetched_attribute(product, attribute):
    if hasattr(product, "prefetched_attr_values"):
        # Use prefetched attributes to avoid extra queries
        return next(
            (
                attr_value.value
                for attr_value in product.prefetched_attr_values
                if attr_value.attribute.code == attribute
            ),
            None,
        )
    else:
        # Fall back to fetching attribute normally if not prefetched
        return attribute_error_as_none(lambda: getattr(product.attr, attribute))


class Product(AbstractProduct):
    @property
    def subtitle(self) -> str:
        return get_prefetched_attribute(self, "subtitle")

    @property
    def legacy_title(self) -> str:
        return get_prefetched_attribute(self, "legacy_title") or self.title
```